# Example of how to use AutoFixture with NSubstitute

Tags: c#, .net, autofixture, nsubstitute

I use NSubstitute a lot.  And I love it.

I am just looking into AutoFixture.  It seems great!

I have seen [AutoFixture for NSubstitute](http://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoFixture.AutoNSubstitute) and seen a few examples in Moq on how to use this feature.

But I can't seem to translate it into NSubstitute.

I tried this:

```
var fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoNSubstituteCustomization());  
var addDest = Substitute.For<IPerson>();
```

Using:

```
public interface IPersonEntity
{    
   int ID { get; set; }
   string FirstName { get; set;}
   string LastName { get; set;}
   DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
   char Gender { get; set; }    
}
```

And I get an object, but none of the properties are populated (kind of the point of AutoFixture).

I also tried:

```
var fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoNSubstituteCustomization());
var result = fixture.Create<IPersonEntity>();
```

That also gave me an object with no populated properties.  (Note if I do the above with a `PersonEntity` class, then the properties are all populated.)

I am sure that there is a way to make this work, but I can't seem to find it.

**So, given my `IPersonEntity` interface above, does anyone know how to use AutoFixture and NSubstitute to give me a populated IPersonEntity object?**

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Instead of customizing the `Fixture` instance with the `AutoNSubstituteCustomization` you may use the customization below:

```
var fixture = new Fixture().Customize(
    new AutoPopulatedNSubstitutePropertiesCustomization());

var result = fixture.Create<IPersonEntity>();
// -> All properties should be populated now.
```

The `AutoPopulatedNSubstitutePropertiesCustomization` is defined as:

```
internal class AutoPopulatedNSubstitutePropertiesCustomization
    : ICustomization
{
    public void Customize(IFixture fixture)
    {
        fixture.ResidueCollectors.Add(
            new Postprocessor(
                new NSubstituteBuilder(
                    new MethodInvoker(
                        new NSubstituteMethodQuery())),
                new AutoPropertiesCommand(
                    new PropertiesOnlySpecification())));
    }

    private class PropertiesOnlySpecification : IRequestSpecification
    {
        public bool IsSatisfiedBy(object request)
        {
            return request is PropertyInfo;
        }
    }
}
```

The difference with the `AutoNSubstituteCustomization` is that the above customization is also [decorated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) with a `Postprocessor` instance to automatically set values for all the public properties of the requested type.

**References**:

The above solution is inspired by the following blog articles by [Mark Seemann](http://blog.ploeh.dk/):

- [How to configure AutoMoq to set up all properties](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2013/04/05/how-to-configure-automoq-to-set-up-all-properties/)
- [How to automatically populate properties with AutoMoq](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2013/04/08/how-to-automatically-populate-properties-with-automoq/)

Comment: Can you do the same for methods? i.e. return interface method values generated by AutoFixture?

Comment: It [can be done](http://nikosbaxevanis.com/blog/2014/02/23/how-to-configure-autofoq-with-foqs-return-strategy/) with [AutoFixture.AutoFoq](http://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoFixture.AutoFoq), though it should be doable with [AutoFixture.AutoNSubstitute](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoFixture.AutoNSubstitute) also.

Comment: I rather thought of something like AutoConfiguredNSubstituteCustomization (answered in a separate question), but thanks anyway.

Comment: Yes, indeed. You may try [AutoConfiguredNSubstituteCustomization](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/blob/master/Src/AutoNSubstitute/AutoConfiguredNSubstituteCustomization.cs).

Answer (score 10):

Though the other answer has been marked as correct back then, I just wanted to add for completeness that you can indeed use AutoNSubstituteCustomization:

```
var fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoNSubstituteCustomization() { ConfigureMembers = true});  
var result = fixture.Create<IPersonEntity>();
```

This will result in the properties being populated.