# How to populate method's return values with AutoFixture

Tags: autofixture, nsubstitute

I would like to auto-generate a method's return values in a non-deterministic manner, i.e. with every call/test run to I expect a method to return random value. For the moment it returns always default values of the method calls:

```
    public interface IReturn
    {
        bool BoolMethod();
        int IntMethod();
    }

    [Fact]
    public void AllReturnsFromAutofixtureMethodsAreFalse()
    {
        IFixture fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoNSubstituteCustomization());
        IEnumerable<IReturn> theBools = fixture.CreateMany<IReturn>();
        Assert.True(theBools.All(tb => tb.BoolMethod() == false));
        Assert.True(theBools.All(tb => tb.IntMethod() == 0));
    }
```

In questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18346427/1970670) one can find a way how to achieve similar thing for properties, however not methods. Any idea?

Comment: For Moq there is the adequate *AutoConfiguredMoqCustomization*. I guess you should look at [AutoConfiguredNSubstituteCustomization](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/blob/master/Src/AutoNSubstitute/AutoConfiguredNSubstituteCustomization.cs).

Comment: This is it, thanks! It seems I used a slightly outdated version of AutoNSubstitute integration, which is why I couldn't find it. Wish I could mark your comment as an answer..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't used *AutoFixture* with *NSubstitute* customization, however by analogy to *Moq* library, It seems that **AutoConfiguredNSubstituteCustomization** class should be used to achieve advanced AutoFixture faking behavior such that you want to. Using it you can auto-generate results from stubbed methods, as well as it is possible to create mock objects chains, injecting freezed objects into chain, an so on.